# How to get blank value without key from JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am creating an application in that I am requesting for data and returning appropriate message but in this API call I only recieve only value not any variable or class so I am not aware how to solve and manage that.

I send below request but it is in JSON.

```
{
    "Email":"test@mytest.com"
}
```

I get below JSON format

> Please check your key.

Response is not receive in any value parameter but I have to display that json as a alert if any one have soultion please help me.

[image]

Comment: I'd write a `JsonConverter`.

Comment: What is your JSON response?

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Please share your request code and server API code.

Comment: @SanishJoseph I get only `Please check your key` in response i am also not get json in c# that's why I am confuse that how to retrieve it

Comment: please share your request and response along with the code where you try to make request.

Comment: @MihirDave I check request and response  parameter and I don't think that it is incorrect because in response i get `OK`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not providing the api key and the server is responding with a non-200OK response and 'Please check your key' is the error message.

Comment: It display me a 200 OK status code and response that's why I am cofuse that what I should do to get that response in string.

Comment: It can still be an api key problem or maybe the email you're query for doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you please review image that I recently upload in my question

Comment: Please show us the 'raw' answer (not the 'pretty' version)

Comment: In response I get some personal information that I can't share in any community but if any thing other than please help us

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or Chrom's extension POSTMAN to check this API? You can post your request and see what's coming back. If it's not 200 -OK there is something wrong in either your request or in the server. Most probably API is expecting some authentication key I guess. Check the response header.